# find same file with in many directories in hierarchical directories in java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to get a  report file which is generated for many applications and stored in directories. But i am not able to get every report when  i search through java. Can any 1 please help me with this  matter.

Comment: You need to elaborate your Q. + put the code which isn't working..

Comment: Unless you tell us exactly what you are planning to do, show us the code you already have, and tell us the problems you are experiencing: no, there is no way to help you. We are not magic.

Comment: May need more details. For example, what the hierarchy of the directories is and what your current solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File Dir =  new File("D:\\log");

    File[] Dir2 = Dir.listFiles(); //Dir2 is inner directory 
    for(int j=0;j
```

/* The add gets the same file names which as differnt path  and that vector can stored and used  */

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search the file in a directory that has subdirectory and goes on then use a recursive search.you can see an example here http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/TraverseTree.html
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Searchforfilesrecursively.htm

Comment: I want the same to be searched with path of it . It gives the only file .but i want we every file to listed

Answer (score 0):

```
private static File find(File dir, String name) {
      File result = null; // no need to store result as String, you're returning File anyway
      File[] dirlist  = dir.listFiles();

      for(int i = 0; i < dirlist.length; i++) { 
        if(dirlist[i].isDirectory()) {
          result = find(dirlist[i], name);
          filedetails.add(result);
          if (dirlist==null)
              break;
          // recursive call found the file; terminate the loop
        } else if(dirlist[i].getName().matches(name)) {
          return dirlist[i]; // found the file; return it
        }
      }
      return result; // will return null if we didn't find anything
    }
```

here is snippet where i am trying details of the file in a vector .